# How can I create a variable to track which image I have set as the "image" property in a PictureBox?

Tags: vb.net

I am working on creating a short game in which the user moves a picturebox across the form and works toward a set destination. I have been able to change the direction that my character faces on the KeyPress event; however, I am unable to use my timer to animate this picturebox via the changing of an integer variable, and as I am already working inside of the loop that is the timer, I cannot create another loop. As I am a novice programmer, as in extremely new to any coding whatsoever, the method of tracking what picture is currently set in the picturebox is unknown to me, and I have researched it to no avail.

This is how I change the image that initially displays in the picturebox on KeyPress and move the picturebox:

```
If aKey or leftKey Then
    picPlayer.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.PlayerRightStand

    'If this is an okay movement, then move
    If picPlayer.Left -= speed >= 0 Then
        picPlayer.Left -= speed

    End If
End If
```

I have tried this to track what image is currently set as the background of picPlayer:

```
If picPlayer.BackgroundImage Is My.Resources.playerRightStand Then
    image = 1
```

...etc., but I think there is a gap in my knowledge or a flaw in my logic because I haven't been able to make this work. If anyone can help with this, which I'm sure actually has a very simple answer, I would greatly appreciate your time and answer. Thanks!

Comment: Oh whoops, first mistake. Thanks for the edit

Comment: I just realised that you are using the `BackgroundImage` property of the `PictureBox` rather than the `Image` property.  Is there a good reason for that?  `Image` is what you should be using pretty much all the time.  You might use `BackgroundImage` as well in some cases but not instead.

Comment: Nope, not really a reason as to why. When I wrote that specific line of code, I guess my mind just defaulted to the BackgroundImage property. I will fix that, thank you for noting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying can't possibly work because `My.Resources` works by creating a new object every time you access it.  That means that even `My.Resources.PlayerRightStand Is My.Resources.PlayerRightStand` would evaluate to `False`.

That means that, even your specific issue aside, you should generally not use `My.Resources` in your general code, but rather assign directly from `My.Resources` to a field and then use that field in your code, e.g.

```
Private playerRightStand As Image = My.Resources.PlayerRightStand
```

That way, you ensure that you only extract that data once and it also means that you can compare the `Image` property of your `PictureBox` to that field at any time and get the expected result.  So:

```
If aKey or leftKey Then
    picPlayer.BackgroundImage = playerRightStand

    'If this is an okay movement, then move
    If picPlayer.Left -= speed >= 0 Then
        picPlayer.Left -= speed

    End If
End If
```

and:

```
If picPlayer.BackgroundImage Is playerRightStand Then
    image = 1
```

You might also consider creating an array and putting all your `Images` in that.  You can then use `Array.IndexOf` to get the index of any specific `Image` and you might also store the index of the current `Image` in a field, meaning that you wouldn't have to keep comparing `Image` references.

Comment: Okay, I see the issue now. I didn't even think about that. Also, I have quite a few animation frames, so an array will probably help in shortening the code - thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a variable to store the current status instead of tracking the image. This has a lot of advantages:

- You can track a lot of status, even those who are not related to a specific image/animation
- You can use the same image for different status
- You can code the logic without having all the images/animation, and implement the graphic later
- You can change the graphic resources, the images, the names without changing the logic

Since you also have different frames, you may store `Arrays` as jmcilhinney suggested.
You could use an enum for that:

```
Public Enum Status
    rightStand
    leftStand
    jumping
    crouching
    NONE
End Enum
```

You can store the previous status and the new one (useful to know if you need to change the image, or loop through animation):

```
Public previousStatus As Status = Status.NONE
Public newStatus As Status = Status.NONE
```

Then you have the status changing logic (just and example):

```
Public Sub changeStatus()

    If leftKey Then
        newStatus = Status.leftStand
    ElseIf rightKey Then
        newStatus = Status.rightStand
    End If

End Sub
```

And the image modification logic (you'll need more work on this part if you want animations loop):

```
Public Sub applyImage()

    If previousStatus = newStatus Then Exit Sub

    Select Case New Status
        Case Status.crouching
            picPlayer.BackgroundImage = playerCrouching
        Case Status.jumping
            picPlayer.BackgroundImage = playerJumping
        Case Status.leftStand
            picPlayer.BackgroundImage = playerLeftStand
        Case Status.rightStand
            picPlayer.BackgroundImage = playerRightStand
    End Select

End Sub
```